# Add jQuery selector to javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, properties

I have a javascript object as  below . i'm using bootstrap 3 for modal object. 
the problem is i cannot access the real modal object inside the 'displayModal' method

```js
 var modalHandler = {
   
   modal: $(".modal"),
   
   modalBody: $(".modal").find(".modal-body"),
   
   displayModal: function(){
     this.modalBody.text("bla bla");
   }
 }
 
 modalHandler.displayModal();
```

Comment: working fine check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/dbr8dxmu/4/,i think u selector is problem

Comment: What is real modal ?

Comment: @bala your fiddler is not working .

Comment: sorry ..check this demo  http://jsfiddle.net/dbr8dxmu/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
displayModal: function(){
   $(this.modalBody).text("bla bla");
}
```

Comment: modalBody is already have a jquery object .Then y u again add jquery object

Comment: because `this` is not a jQuery object in that case. @Bala

Comment: @jai yes but **this.modalBody** this refers to  modalHandler.modalBody

Comment: @jai check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/dbr8dxmu/4/, this is instance of modalHandler

Comment: @Bala the title says *Add jQuery selector to javascript object*, I think Zumry has to change/modify his problem with the title. From the title the answer works properly with `$(this.modalBody).text("bla bla");` [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/dbr8dxmu/5/)

Comment: @RohanKumar That is no need ..Read again OP post i cannot access the real modal object inside the 'displayModal' method

Comment: @RohanKumar That is working fine without wrapping jquery object ,there is already having that

Comment: @RohanKumar This is not working on real scnario. as bala said i can't access real modal object inside $() .

Comment: @ZumryMohamed can you make an online demo for it?

Comment: i found the issue instead 
modalBody: $(".modal").find(".modal-body"),
we should use 
modalBody:$(".modal .modal-body"),